# Django: how to use forms.ValidationError and show messages in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Below I show code where I have created a custom `clean()` for a form, and (I think) raise appropriate validation errors when necessary. I can show `{{ form.errors }}` in the template, which is a dict, and can parse the dict in the template to get it to display the proper error message, but my approach must be wrong. So my questions are 1) should I change the implementation of ValidationError in my form? and 2) how do I best show the error messages in a template?

```
class ParticipantLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    passpin = forms.CharField(label='PIN', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    error_messages = {
        'email_unknown': 'The email credential is unknown.',
        'invalid_pass': 'Invalid password or PIN',
        'inactive': 'This account is inactive',
    }

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('username')  # because this is in settings
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        passpin = self.cleaned_data.get('passpin')

        if email and password and passpin:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(
                email=email,
                password=password,
                passpin=passpin,
            )

            if self.user_cache is None:
                try:
                    participant = Participant.objects.get(email=email)
                except Participant.DoesNotExist:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        self.error_messages['email_unknown'],
                        code='email_unknown',
                        params={'email': self.username_field}
                    )

                if participant.password != password or participant.passpin != passpin:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        self.error_messages['invalid_pass'],
                        code='invalid_pass',
                    )

            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['inactive'],
                    code='inactive',
                )

        return self.cleaned_data
```

My rudimentary template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% for k, message in form.errors.items %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} {{ field.errors }}
        {% endfor %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have, apart from the fact that you're showing errors twice (once at the top, and then once per field)?

Comment: `clean()` adds items to the `form.errors` dict with the key of `__all__`. It does not create error messages which can be found in the template using `{{ field.errors }}`, which is one issue. Additionally, I wonder if `{% for k, message in form.errors.items %}` is the proper why to show the form error messages. Seems unexpectedly cumbersome to me.